# LendingClub Rest API Submit Order reponse 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: python, post, request, http-post, lending-club-api

I have the below code which i've written after looking over many over modules and questions on stack, but i keep getting back a 500 reponse error when trying to submit an order? the text of the resposne is always something like "Internal sever error" followed by a 13? digit number that is always different

```
import requests
import json
my_aid = xxxxxxxx
loan_id = yyyyyyyyy
url = 'htpps://api.lendingclub.com/api/investors/v1/accounts/xxxxxxxxx/orders'
header = {'Authorization':*my_AUTH*}
payload = {
                 'aid':my_aid,
                 'orders':[{
                          'loanId':loan_id,
                          'requestedAmount':25.0,
                           }]    
}
resp = requests.post(url,headers=header,data=json.dumps(payload))
```

any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

change header to;

header = {'Authorization':*myAUTH*,'Content-Type':'application/json'}